# Rails 6 ransacker to filter through User's polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I'm trying to create a filter inside of Active Admin `Conversation` file, which will show me the User by his full name (user full name = user.first_name + user.last_name). User and Conversation are related by polymorphic association like below:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations, as: :sendable
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sendable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Because ActiveAdmin use Ransack under the hood I was trying to declare ransacker inside of `User` model and refer to it in `admin/conversations.rb`, like below:

```
#admin/conversations.rb

ActiveAdmin.register Conversation do
  filter :sendable_of_User_type_full_name_cont, as: :string, label: 'User (name)'
end

#models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
...

  ransacker :full_name, formatter: proc { |v| v.strip } do |parent|
    "#{parent.table[:first_name]} #{parent.table[:last_name]}"
  end
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

> NoMethodError in Admin::ConversationsController#index
>
> undefined method `matches' for #String:0x00007fa90ceb6560
>
> Did you mean?
> match
> match?
>
> Extracted source (around line #33):
> 31 arel_pred = arel_predicate_for_attribute(attribute)
> 32 arel_values = formatted_values_for_attribute(attribute)
> 33 predicate = attr_value_for_attribute(attribute).public_send(arel_pred, arel_values)
> 34
> 35 if in_predicate?(predicate)
> 36  predicate.right = predicate.right.map do |pr|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those struggling with a similar problem - I found a nice explanation in the [docs](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers#5-search-on-a-concatenated-full-name-from-first_name-and-last_name-several-examples)

Ransnacker change accordingly will do the trick:

```
# models/users.rb
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
    parent.table[:first_name], parent.table[:last_name])
end
```